# Rails 4 x Bootstrap 3: how to apply custom style to select field

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu

I am building a web app with Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3.

In my sign up form, I have several fields including a `time_zone` `select`:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name, "FIRST NAME" %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name, "LAST NAME" %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time_zone, "TIME ZONE" %>
    <%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, :class => :timezone %>
</div>
```

I have been able to style the `first_name` and `last_name` fields, but I cannot seem to apply a `padding` or remove the `border-radius` of the `time_zone` field:

[image]

This is what I have in my `css` file:

```
#user_first_name, #user_last_name {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#user_time_zone {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

How can I get the same style for the select field as for the other two regular text fields?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Well, I could provide a JSFiddle, but there would not be more code than what's already in my question... I am not using any custom JavaScript beside default Bootstrap functions. What would you need exactly?

Comment: Jsfiddle makes easier to understand your problem and solve it fast.

Comment: I am happy to share any code I have. I am just not sure of what I can provide in addition to what is already in my question... What would you need?

Comment: I can send you this, but because we are not in a Rails environment, it does not work properly: https://jsfiddle.net/7vg9exg5/

Comment: I'm not expert in Rails. Is it possible to post your compiled html?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Here we go: https://jsfiddle.net/7vg9exg5/

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand Rails(For example ` f.label :time_zone`). I only need HTML of your work without any Rails.

Comment: Yes, I sent you a new JSFiddle with the compiled HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/7vg9exg5/

Comment: That fiddle contains `erb` tags, so it's not actually the compiled HTML.  Do a right-click -> 'inspect element' on one of those fields, and copy the HTML of those three divs straight from your browser's dev tools.  While you're in there, highlight the `div` containing the `select` and look at the styles.  Assuming you're using the right css selector, do you see `border-radius: 0;` in the list of styles?  Is it struck through?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had done, but for some reason, you did not get the correct JSFiddle link. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/7vg9exg5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your jsfiddle link and your time zone select seems to be okay. 
( refer to image attached )

[image]